# ng-drag-drop not working after angular 6 migration

Tags: angular6, ngdraggable

I am using ng-drag-drop component in my application. I recently migrated my angular application from v4.2 to v6. Unfortunately the drag and drop is not functioning properly. Getting the below error as soon i drag.

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function
    at Droppable.push../node_modules/ng-drag-drop/src/directives/droppable.directive.js.Droppable.allowDrop (droppable.directive.js:151)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (droppable.directive.js:161)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Subject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
    at Draggable.push../node_modules/ng-drag-drop/src/directives/draggable.directive.js.Draggable.dragStart (draggable.directive.js:112)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (CustodianCardComponent.html:1)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: can you post code...

Comment: I'm pretty sure angular 6 differs from Angular 4 in the way you import certain observable methods

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading rxjs and rxjs-compat to 6.2.1

This seems to be the original issue ReactiveX/rxjs#4070